# Opengles 2.0 multi Textures fade out one by one

Tags: textures, opengl-es2, cocos2d

I have multi textures, A was drawed on top of B, B was on top of C ...., ( **like Picture 1**) .I want to fade out A first, then B will appear and fade out either... But when A fade out, background color appeared on top of B, ( **like Picture 1** )? Why? What should I do?
I have enable Blend like this

`glClearColor(0, 104.0/255.0, 55.0/255.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

and Fragment shader

```
"void main(void) { // 2\n"
"gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);\n"
"gl_FragColor  *= alpha;\n"
```

" }\n"

**Picture 1：**  background color is green, A and B are both rectangle, A is on top of B

[image]

**Picure 2** When I fade out A, the result like this:

[image]

I aso try to use `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` but it doesn't work either.

**Update 1 shader **

const GLchar *vertex_shader_source_ =
{
    attribute vec4 Position;

```
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

varying vec4 DestinationColor;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn; // New
varying vec2 TexCoordOut; // New

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview *Position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;// New

"}
```

};

const GLchar *fragment_shader_source_ =
{
    uniform highp float alpha;
    uniform sampler2D Texture;// New

```
varying highp vec2 TexCoordOut; // New

void main(void) { // 2
gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
"gl_FragColor.a  = alpha;
```

}
};

Comment: Could you share the entire shader code ? I understand you have 3 different quads and not one quad with three textures, can you confirm?

Comment: @ elenfoiro78 I had updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

And render the images in back-to-front order.

Most likely the depth test is what's preventing the other images from rendering.

Comment: Yes, It's oK now, thank you. But I  don't know why? if A is on top of B,  when I enable depth test,  draw in order B->A, then A is not visible, If I disable depth test, A will appear again. can you tell me why? thanks.

Comment: The depth test is usually used to prevents drawing pixels behind (or equal) to other pixels. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering and https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Test